# SeekBar thumb (9 patch) not recognized

Tags: android, nine-patch, android-seekbar

I have the following code for my seek bar

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/sbCardSpeed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="50"
    android:secondaryProgress="0"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seek_thumb" />
```

seek_thumb is a 9 patch image file called seek_thumb.9.png. The problem that this drawable is not recognized and the thumb is not shown. However when I remove the .9. from the file name then my thumb is shown with the black guide lines

Any idea why or how to fix this?

Comment: Are there any messages of note in LogCat when you have the nine-patch in there? Does `draw9patch` complain at all about the image if you try loading it in that tool? Have you tried copying the standard thumb image from your SDK and using that, to see if it works?

Comment: No to all of the questions. The standard thumb image from sdk is not 9 patch, is it?

Comment: "The standard thumb image from sdk is not 9 patch, is it?" -- I haven't looked. I assumed it was, otherwise you would not be bothering with a nine-patch in your custom version. I would stick to the structure the SDK uses. If they use a regular (non-nine-patch) PNG, use that.

Comment: I guess you are absolutely right :) Thanks a lot. How would I find the thumb in the SDK? I thought the SDK is like a jar file

Comment: `$SDK/platforms/$VERSION/data/res/`, where `$SDK` is wherever your Android SDK is installed on your development machine and `$VERSION` is some API level. That location is full of resources. Poke through one of the drawable directories (e.g., `drawable-hdpi/`) and look for `seek_thumb_normal.png`, `seek_thumb_pressed.png`, and `seek_thumb_selected.png`.

Comment: Awsome thank you, I wish I can accept your comment as an asnwer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nine-patch PNG files are almost exclusively used for background of widgets, such as the background of a `Button`. The `SeekBar` thumb is probably not being drawn as a background. I would have expected your nine-patch PNG to still work, but apparently it doesn't.

The standard `SeekBar` thumb image is not a nine-patch, as it does not need to be resized the way a `Button` background does. Hence, I'd stick with standard PNG files for the different states, and reference them from an appropriate `StateListDrawable` pointing to your PNG files.

You can find the stock drawables in `$SDK/platforms/$VERSION/data/res/`, where `$SDK` is wherever your Android SDK is installed on your development machine and `$VERSION` is some API level. The standard `StateListDrawable` which is the actual `SeekBar` thumb should be in `drawable/`, while the PNGs used by that `StateListDrawable` are in the various density-dependent directories (e.g., `drawable-hdpi/`) as `seek_thumb_normal.png`, `seek_thumb_pressed.png`, and `seek_thumb_selected.png`.